# How to extract nupkg package which was downloaded by release pipeline into target machines from azure artifacts

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to extract the nupkg package which was downloaded into target machine by azure release pipeline from azure artifacts. i tried using nuget cli commands but i'm getting errors like file was not found errors.

Comment: Could you provide full error information about nuget cli command ? "Like file was not found " means  your package file in azure artifacts or something else ?

Comment: You could edit your case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and provide more information in order to make it easy for other to identify problem cause.